# I want to destroy and recreate the table using the same id

Tags: jquery

`linkForBC` is checkbox id and if I click this checkbox, I want to create the new table Id option_list.

This is my html design.

```
 <tr class="checkList">
          <td class="bcid">BC</td>
          <td>
            <table id="option_list" border="0" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody id="tbodyid">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td></td>
```

If click it goes to  $('#linkForBC') this method.

```
function getDropDown(itemsSelected) {
if ($('#linkForBC').attr("checked")) {
    Enterprisegateway.Models.Constants.findOver({}, function (result) {
        for (var i in result)
            methodName = i;
        var res = IsValidSession(result[methodName]);
        if (res === false || res === "false") {
            $.hideprogress();
        }

        var json = $.parseJSON(result[methodName]);
        if (json === null || json === undefined || json === '') {
            $.hideprogress();
        }

        var result = json.Result;
        var data = json.Data;
        if (result === 0) {
            plantTypes = data;
        }
        showEquipments(data, itemsSelected);
    });

}
else {
    //$(".checkList tr").style.display = "none";
    $(".bcid").style.display = "none";
    $("#tbodyid").empty();
}

}
```

If I click, I want to create table and if I uncheck the table, it should destroy table and then again if I check, I want to create table.

```
 $('#linkForBC').live("click", function () {
        var itemsSelected = '';
        getDropDown(itemsSelected);
    });
```

This method for create table.

```
function showEquipments(data, itemsSelected) {
    if (data == undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    var newLi = "<tr>";
    newLi += "<td style=text-align:left;padding-left:5px;width:70%;>";
    newLi += "<select id= test0 " + "  name='access' lang = " + "'" + "OPTIONS" + "'" + " class='types' multiple='multiple'  width='100%;' ";
    for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
        if (itemsSelected !== null && itemsSelected !== "" && itemsSelected.indexOf(data[k].Id) > -1) {
            var selected = "selected";
            newLi += "  <option id=" + data[k].Id + "  class='EquipmentOptions' value=" + data[k].Id + " " + selected + " >" + data[k].Name + " </option>";
        }
        else {
            newLi += "  <option id=" + data[k].Id + " class='EquipmentOptions' value=" + data[k].Id + " >" + data[k].Name + "</option>";
        }
    }

    newLi += "</select>";
    newLi += "</td>";
    newLi += "</tr>";
    $('#option_list').append(newLi);
    $("#test0").dropdownchecklist({
        onComplete: function (selector) {
            values = '';
            itemsToAdds = [];
            for (i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++) {
                if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].id != "")) {
                    if (values != "")
                        values += ";";
                    values += selector.options[i].id;
                    itemsToAdds.push(selector.options[i].id)
                }
                if (values) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` instead of `live`

```
$(function(){
    $('document').on('click','#linkForBC',function(){
          var itemsSelected = '';
          getDropDown(itemsSelected);
    })
})
```

GetDROPDOWN

```
function getDropDown(itemsSelected) {
 if ($('#linkForBC:checked').val()) {
    Enterprisegateway.Models.Constants.findOver({}, function (result) {
        for (var i in result)
            methodName = i;
        var res = IsValidSession(result[methodName]);
        if (res === false || res === "false") {
            $.hideprogress();
        }

        var json = $.parseJSON(result[methodName]);
        if (json === null || json === undefined || json === '') {
            $.hideprogress();
        }

        var result = json.Result;
        var data = json.Data;
        if (result === 0) {
            plantTypes = data;
        }
        showEquipments(data, itemsSelected);
    });

}
else {
    //$(".checkList tr").style.display = "none";
    $(".bcid").style.display = "none";
    $("#tbodyid").empty();
}

}
```

ShowEquipment

```
function showEquipments(data, itemsSelected) {
    //  Create table and append 
}
```